# Installed dimmer switch caused another switch to stop working

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch, dimmer-switch

I installed a dimmer in my bedroom today and I just realised that the dimmer in my mom's room and in the corridor is not working anymore...

Followed standard procedure :
Breaker off, changed the old switch for the dimmer and then turned the breaker on again and the dimmer is working fine.

I can't find any help online...

If it can help, it's a dimmer with a 3-way compatibility, but I didn't connect the wire for it.

I'm a beginner, I wondered if any of you could help, thank you. (Did I mixed up the Ground wire with the black one?)

[image]

Comment: Are the two dimmers on the same breaker, or different breakers?  Can you post a photo of the inside of the box in your bedroom?

Comment: Were there any extra wires left over?

Comment: Did you record the positions of the wires on the original switch before starting? This may help you in sorting the issue.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you, and please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to participate here.

Comment: I can't really test if they are on the same breaker now... You guys would want a picture from inside the dimmer?

Comment: Not inside the dimmer, but a picture of the wiring inside the wall box.

Comment: Done ......................

Comment: How do you have the wires connected to the new dimmer? Does you dimmer specify which place the hot does and which is for the switched hot? I assume this dimmer does not need a neutral connected--is this right?

Comment: If you could send pic of every box and switch you touched. Seems like bad splice or mixed up travelers

Comment: All whites on switches are not always a neutral . Many types of splicing in different cases  .

Comment: I don't think there are any travelers; I assume these are separate 1-way switches. The right cable is presumably from the ceiling box: B or R hot; other switched hot; W neutral.

Comment: Modern wiring uses a three conductor cable to have a neutral in a switch box and I assume the R and B would be the switch loop and te W would be a neutral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need a multi-meter or a non-contact voltage tester to find out which wires are hot, but if you want to you could try to do this without testing.

The white wires are "neutrals" (not grounds). Looks like you have bare grounds connected to the metal box with screws in the back. Leave those alone.

Do the B, R and W wires in the right cable go to the light in your room? If so, the B & W wires in the cable to the left are the feed to the hall and the other bedroom. The B is hot and the W is neutral. Somehow you disconnected the feed and did not reconnect it.

Probably the B and the R on the right were connected to the original switch. If so, one or the other of the B and R is always hot and the other is the switched hot which controls the light in your room.

The B in the left hand cable should be connected to the always hot from the right cable. The two W wires should be connected to each other (and to nothing else).

Comment: I screwed the ground from the dimmer to one of the screws and the two black ones to the black of the dimmer and everything was working well!